# Simplecart Total Weight

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, shopping-cart

This page describes my shopping cart which is using the [simpleCart](http://simplecartjs.com) JavaScript library, and the function alters the shipping cost of my cart. How can I implement my function to be used with my cart?

```
<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
<a href="#" class="simpleCart_empty">Svuota Carrello</a>
<strong>Sub Total: <span class="simpleCart_total"></span></strong> <br />
<strong>TAX:<span class="simpleCart_taxCost"</span> </strong> <br />
<strong>Productions numbers:<span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span></strong> <br />
<strong>Total Weight:???????</span></strong> <br />
<strong>Shipping:????</strong> <br />
```

My current function is:

```
me.shipping = function() 
{  
    var q = 0;  
    q += item.weight*item.quantity;  

    if(q <= 3000){  
        return 19.00;  
    }  
    if((q <= 10000)) {  
        return 23.00;  
    }  
    if((q <= 20000)){  
        return 24.00;  
    }  
    if((q <= 30000)){  
        return 26.00;  
    }  
    if((q <= 50000)){  
        return 32.00;  
    }  
    if((q <= 75000)){  
        return 35.00;  
    }  
    if((q <= 100000)){  
        return 39.00;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per simpleCart Documentation, there are many ways they allow you to customize shipping costs.  One in particular I saw was almost exactly what I think (post was difficult to read) you want:

```
CartItem.prototype.shipping=function(){
// we are using a 'size' field to calculate the shipping,
// so we first make sure the item has a size
    if(this.size){
        if( this.size == 'small' ){
            return this.quantity*5.00;
        } else if( this.size == 'large') {
            return this.quantity*7.50;
        } else {
            return this.quantity*10.00;
        }
    } else {
        // use a default of $2.00 per item if there is no 'size' field
        return this.quantity*2.00;
    }
}
```

This shows how you can edit how shipping is calculated. This example any many others are available per their site documentation at: http://simplecartjs.com/documentation.html

Comment: Tanks. The function for shipping different for weight is not possible. My client commerce vine for weight. Weight < 3000 = 19 euros; weight <10000 = 24 euros etc...